# Chrome lagging extremely badly after Windows reinstall

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, crossfire

I recently installed a second 7970 in crossfire and at the same time installed Windows 8.1

Now whenever I use chrome for any longer period of time I will always hit a point where it begins to lag.
Scrolling, selecting text and just plain moving the mouse around becomes sluggish and unresponsive.

Why is this?

Comment: More information about the system is required to help

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you don't have any extensions running that can cause the slowdown. Visit `chrome://extensions` in your browser to see what is loaded and disable those you aren't using. You may also be viewing some pages that are taking up lots of memory. Visit `about:memory` to see what pages are taking up the most memory.
Lastly, you might try running Chrome in incognito mode, which disables all extensions and see if it helps.
From http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/02/google-chrome-safe-mode.html:

> > If you want to create a shortcut that opens Chrome in incognito mode, duplicate an existing Chrome shortcut, right-click on the shortcut, select "Properties" and append this flag to the target value: `--incognito` (don't forget to add a space to separate the flag).

Comment: Extensions are not an issue, I'm using none. Nothing is using an inordinate amount of memory.